# Access-Control/Authorization for Edit/Update API endpoints with MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization, mean, jwt

In this app, the only user with permission to edit or destroy a post should be the user that created the post.

I have a route to authenticate a user to give them a token. I also have a route to verify a token:

```
apiRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {

  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
        });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next(); 
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided.'
    });
  }
});
```

What is the standard way to ensure that only the proper user can edit and destroy a post using tokens?

```
apiRouter.route('/posts/:post_id')

    .put(function(req, res) {
        Post.findById(req.params.post_id, function(err, post) {
            if (err) res.send(err);

            if (req.body.title) post.title = req.body.title;
            if (req.body.body) post.body = req.body.body;
            if (req.body.author) post.author = req.body.author;

            post.save(function(err) {
                if (err) res.send(err);

                // return a message
                res.json({ message: 'Post updated!' });
            });
        });
    })

    .delete [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the logic for checking whether the user is a verified user or not in the middleware and probably make use of rbac (role based access control), defining the permissions/ roles for the user.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? What is rbac?

Comment: For any user related routes, you first need to authenticate the users (usually by a token). Once you have figured out who the user is for that particular request, you could attach that information to their session (as in request.session = user). The `user` object can contain more information about their roles (by a database lookup or so) and then determine in the middleware if the user is authorized for a route or not. See https://github.com/seeden/rbac for more examples